Where is "Import Images as Planes" in 4.2?
I just installed Blender 4.2 and can't find "Import Images as Planes" in new extensions. Why it was removed? Where I can find such a useful function?

In a list about add-ons previously shipped with Blender, there is no button to install add-on "Import Images as Planes":


Add-on "Import Images as Planes" has been replaced by the native operator "Mesh Plane",
that you can find in Shift+A ⇾ Image ⇾ Mesh Plane


Achievement unlocked: Clairvoyance
